# Android : How to calculate total in model array-list?

Tags: java, android, model, pojo

I want to create `totalHaveMoney` I was try to looping data `income - expense` in `totalMoney` method, but this failed. It is only getting `income` from one data, so the calculation doesn't work.

Model :

```
public class MoneyManager {
    String name, category;
    String date, description, key;
    Long income, expense, totalMoney;

    public MoneyManager(String name, String category, String date, Long income,Long expense , String description) {
        this.name = name;
        this.category = category;
        this.date = date;
        this.income = income;
        this.expense = expense;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public MoneyManager() {
    }
    public Long totalMoney(){
        Long haveMoney = getIncome();

        for (int i = 0; i < this.getIncome(); i++){
            haveMoney -= getExpense();
        }
        return haveMoney;
    }

    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public void setKey(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public Long getExpense() {
        return expense;
    }

    public void setExpense(Long expense) {
        this.expense = expense;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(String category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public Long getIncome() {
        return income;
    }

    public void setIncome(Long income) {
        this.income = income;
    }

    public Long getTotalMoney() {
        return totalMoney;
    }

    public void setTotalMoney(Long totalMoney) {
        this.totalMoney = totalMoney;
    }
}
```

When im getting data:

```
  MoneyManager money = moneyManagers.get(position);

        Resources resources = context.getResources();
        Locale rupiah = new Locale("id", "id");

        holder.textName.setText(String.valueOf(money.totalMoney()));
        holder.textDate.setText(money.getDate());
```

The result of `money.totalMoney()` is the same as `income`.

Comment: I can not see any `lists` or `arrays` in your code - please show what you mean

Comment: i just want calculate ```income - expense``` but im as always failed

Comment: why are you looping?  Why not `return getIncome() - getExpense();` - no loop necessary.

Comment: i want to getting all arraylist data and calculate them. but i have no idea, because my post in above calculating single data only

Comment: As I said before - I can not see any lists or arrays in your code.  Do you have a `List` of `MoneyManager` objects?

Comment: yes in firebase

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a `List` of you can iterate through them and add

```
long sum = 0;
for (MoneyManager mm : listOfMoneyManager) { // or whatever your local variable is
    sum += mm.getIncome() - mm.getExpense();
}

// after the iteration you have the total

System.out.println (sum);
```